# No permission to access private_procedure `var/1'

Tags: prolog, metaprogramming, prolog-metainterpreter

I have written a simple unification algorithm (with occurs check) in Prolog, using meta-programming techniques. I am using SWI-Prolog 7.4.2.

I want to use it inside a meta-interpreter, such as the classic *vanilla meta-interpreter:*

```
solve(true) :- !.
solve((A,B)) :- solve(A), solve(B).
solve(A) :- clause(A,B), solve(B).
```

If I try for example `solve(odd(X))` it works, giving as the first solution `X = s(0)`. (Where the clauses are `odd(s(0)).` and `odd(s(s(X))) :- odd(X).`)

But if I try to execute the unification algorithm using `solve`, it doesn't work any more. Since I use meta-predicates like `var/1` inside my unification algorithm, I tried with simpler goals.

The problem is this one: if I input `solve(var(X))`, it says `No permission to access private_procedure 'var/1'`.
I can't find useful information about this, can someone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
solve(true) :- !.
solve((A,B)) :- solve(A), solve(B).
solve(A) :- predicate_property(A,built_in), !, call(A).
solve(A) :- clause(A,B), solve(B).
```

But this will not work the same in all Prolog systems... but the implicit hint should help you move forward.